# Misallignment FFT values

Tags: matlab, fft, octave

I have simple matlab script where i perform the FFT over.
The basic signal script is as following

```
N=1024;
Fs = 512;
x=0:1/Fs:(N-1)/Fs;
y1 = rand(1,length(x));
y = sin(2*pi * 8*x +pi/4) + sin(2*pi * 2*x)+0.25*y1;

Y = fft(y);
samples = 1:N;
Yri = [real(Y)';imag(Y)')
```

when i look to the values of my FFT i see something strange.
I have always understand that the FFT is symmetric. That should mean that `Y(0) = Y(N-1)` but when i look  to my values it is like this

```
132.2359908746976    0
-1.129890364069726   0.2718866753339693
-0.9898054379204928  -0.09764592088929502
-0.2647724958644289  0.8350994813335381
-1.868448885843761   -510.8397750064335
-2.379196462710131   1.624049527127165
-2.753782883986133   -1.523597086410836
1.949383081952796    1.183816362344675
-0.3039050016066438  -2.096280913074243
-1.506203056327606   -1.690278489723206
0.6347563438325143   -1.587693811158511
0.5233967784525266   1.730435526309953
1.052101496393941    0.3182729933856796
-1.512217438563844   -0.9760620411480605
2.180241723969081    0.4304125102798211
1.999781891166625    0.778355882266289
361.5665600468327    -360.9118750913981
1.427992040614833    1.296361507220924
...
...
0.2265259661047323   0.6794647303926733
1.427992040614833    -1.296361507220924
361.5665600468327    360.9118750913981
1.999781891166625    -0.778355882266289
2.180241723969081    -0.4304125102798211
-1.512217438563844   0.9760620411480605
1.052101496393941    -0.3182729933856796
0.5233967784525266   -1.730435526309953
0.6347563438325143   1.587693811158511
-1.506203056327606   1.690278489723206
-0.3039050016066438  2.096280913074243
1.949383081952796    -1.183816362344675
-2.753782883986133   1.523597086410836
-2.379196462710131   -1.624049527127165
-1.868448885843761   510.8397750064335
-0.2647724958644289  -0.8350994813335381
-0.9898054379204928  0.09764592088929502
-1.129890364069726  -0.2718866753339693
```

My 2 frequencys are the values around 360 and around 510. 
Bus as you can see the value 510 is the 5th value from the beginning, but the forth value from the end.
The same with the value 360 is around the 17th value from the beginning but the 16th from the end.

What is the orgin from this. how to fix this or is this normal behavour??

Thanks

Comment: The first value correspond to the nil-frequency and stores the mean value of your signal. It is a completely normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For strictly real input y: The FFT result

```
Y(i) == complex_conjugate(Y(N-i))
```

Y(0) is the DC term which is it's own complex conjugate, and thus has no (other) mirrored result bin.  For even N, Y(N/2) also has no mirrored bin.

Comment: If `Y(0)` Don't have a complex conjugate than is thus `Y(1) = complex conjugate Y(N-1),Y(2) = complex conjugate Y(N-2) , etc` and in the end there is one value left what don't have an complex conjugate eighter...   
I want calculate back the Fourier decomposition. To get the sine and cosines i need everytime two values... and this problem confuses me

Answer (score -1):

You need to apply `fftshift()` on your FFT values to get what you want.

Comment: Oke as the first is the nul frequency than should the last also an nul frequency. otherwise it is not symetrical.
What changed so that when i add `fftshift()` so that it is right again. fft shift should just move `N/2 samples` around. This shouldn't have any effect at the nul frequency.